# c++, обновление данных в DataGridView

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Делаю самую что есть простую программу, которая: выводит, добавляет, ОБНОВЛЯЕТ, удаляет данные в БД access. Всё работает, кроме обновления данных. Делаю по видео, в котором тот же самый запрос успешно работает, а у меня нет. Проверил все данные в запросе, саму БД, всё тщетно. Выручайте.

```
System::Void Project4::MyForm::button_update_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    // выбор нужной строки для добавления

    if (dataGridView1->SelectedRows->Count != 1)
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Выбрите одну строку для добавления!", "Внимание!");
        return;
    }

    // узнаём индекс выбранной строки

    int index = dataGridView1->SelectedRows[0]->Index;

    // проверка данных

    if (dataGridView1->Rows[index]->Cells[0]->Value == nullptr ||
        dataGridView1->Rows[index]->Cells[1]->Value == nullptr ||
        dataGridView1->Rows[index]->Cells[2]->Value == nullptr ||
        dataGridView1->Rows[index]->Cells[3]->Value == nullptr) {
        MessageBox::Show("Не все данные введены!", "Внимание!");
        return;
    }

    // считываем данные

    String^ id = dataGridView1->Rows[index]->Cells[0]->Value->ToString();
    String^ name = dataGridView1->Rows[index]->Cells[1]->Value->ToString();
    String^ price = dataGridView1->Rows[index]->Cells[2]->Value->ToString();
    String^ count = dataGridView1->Rows[index]->Cells[3]->Value->ToString();

    // подключение к БД
    String^ connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=Database.mdb";
    OleDbConnection^ dbConnection = gcnew OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    // запрос

    dbConnection->Open(); // открываем соединение
    String^ query = "UPDATE [table_name] SET name='" + name + "', price = " + price + ", count=" + count + " WHERE id = " + id;//запрос
    OleDbCommand^ dbComand = gcnew OleDbCommand(query, dbConnection); // команда

    // выполняем запрос

    if (dbComand->ExecuteNonQuery() != 1)
    MessageBox::Show("Ошибка выполнения запроса!", "Ошибка!");
else
    MessageBox::Show("Данные добавлены!", "Готово!");

    // закрываем соединение с БД

    dbConnection->Close();

    return System::Void();
}
```

Comment: В программировании нет такого понятия: "Не работает". Есть конкретная ошибка с точным описанием!

Comment: Хм, ну, ошибки здесь никакой нет. Нет верного пути решения. Это было описано выше